# Bootstrap wells issue on safari browser

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, webkit

```html
<div class="well">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="btn-col" button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#helplinks"><p id="scrollertext">What is a Trust Deed?      &#8595</p></button></div>
       <div id="helplinks" class="collapse">
        <p id="scrollerinfo"> A Trust Deed is a formal agreement made between the person in debt and their creditors. The agreement allows the debtor to make regular monthly payments towards clearing their debt. All further interest and charges on the outstanding debt are stopped. At the end of the arrangement, any unpaid debt is written off.</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Just starting out on web design and coding..
Have made quite a basic website with some Bootstrap wells, that cascade to give further information. 
All good on windows and android platforms, website works great. But its not working on safari browsers? 
I've used the latest bootstrap.min file as advised by some colleagues - but this aint helping. Anybody any ideas?

Here is the code I have used for the bootstrap well (but as said before, I'm not sure if this is where the issue is? As it works fine on android and windows platforms?)

Comment: Can you provide the code that is causing your issue?

Comment: With being new to this sort of thing though, I'm not entirely sure at all what part of my index.html or boostrap.min.css file is causing the issue.  I don't want to post the full code if you know what I mean lol maybe end up booted of the site